# What is the ratio of milk and water in the resultant mixture?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A 20 litre mixture of milk and water contains milk and water in the ratio 3 : 2. 10 litres of the mixture is removed and replaced with pure milk and the operation is repeated once more. At the end of the two removal and replacement, what is the ratio of milk and water in the resultant mixture?

Step 1. When 10 litres of the mixture is removed, 6 litres of milk is removed and 4 litres of water is removed. Therefore, there will be 6 litres of milk and 4 litres of water left in the container. It is then replaced with pure milk of 10 litres. Now the container will have 16 litres of milk and 4 litres of water.

Step 2. When 10 litres of the new mixture is removed, 8 litres of milk and 2 litres of water is removed. The container will have 8 litres of milk and 2 litres of water in it. Now 10 litres of pure milk is added. Therefore, the container will have 18 litres of milk and 2 litres of water in it at the end of the second step.

Can anyone please explain it to me how we calculated that in second mixture we have to remove 8 litres of milk and 2 litres of water?

Answer (score 1):

**Initial State**:$\frac{3}{5}20 = 12$ liters Milk, $\frac{2}{5}20 = 8$ liters Water.

**After First step**:

remove: $\frac{2}{5}10 = 4$ liters water and $\frac{3}{5}10 = 6$ liters milk

add: $10$liters milk

finally: $12 - 6 + 10 = 16$ liters milk, $8 - 4 = 4$ liters water

**After Second step**:

remove: $\frac{16}{20}10 = 8$ liters milk, and $\frac{4}{20}10 = 2$ liters water

add: $10$liters milk

finally: $16 - 8 + 10 = 18$ liters milk, $4 - 2 = 2$ liters water

**Final State**:

So, the result ratio is 9:1 for milk to water.